# How handle bot to count pageviews

Tags: algorithm, automation, bots

I don't know how exactly handle this situation. I have a directory where I count the pageviews for each item. For authenticated users I only count as new pageview after a delay of 200 seconds between requests. For unauthenticated users I use the IP and also 200 seconds of delay.

I use a redis SETEX to verify and then the key will expire after 200 seconds. If the key doesn't exist, then insert a new page view.

Something like this

- `item_id:user_id` (authenticated users)
- `item_id:ip` (unauthenticated users)

Well, this works fine until a user try to increment intentionally the page views for a specific item. I have almost 3000 views for a specific item only yesterday (in last year the page has only 150 views...). So, he created some bot to visit the page with a delay to avoid my validation.

I need to register legit pageviews, but I need to avoid the type of fraud. Any idea?

Comment: This question is quite opinionated and does not really fit Stack Overflow very well.

Comment: Nevertheless: You can avoid fraud by changing your definition of a "page-view". Several well known tools for measuring page-views such as Google Analytics use time-outs to avoid double page-views but also show things like unique hits (not counting double hits within a session), besides this they also record other traffic information such as the user-agent which can often be used to avoid certain (search-)bots. However preventing spam is very difficult if not impossible because a bot can very easily pretend to be human, unless you build in some human-verification system like a captcha.

Comment: What's your definition of fraud? You've created a rule that filters requests that are fewer then 200 seconds apart but seemingly that's not a rule that separates 'fraudulent' from 'legit' views.
If you exactly specify your 'fraud' definition, you could design an appropriate filter, such as: max. 2 views / hour, max. 4 / day, max 8 / month.

Comment: @TomLankhorst Currently I don't have exactly a definition for fraud. But when I see in logs a request every X seconds I know that is not a normal behaviour for a real user. But well, is not easy to create a rule where you determinate if the requests are consecutive or not and  grouped by identity.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the best way for handling bots is a way like **Google Analytics**.

> Google Analytics works by inserting a JavaScript snippet into the
>   header of your website. This snippet counts a page view whenever a
>   visitor triggers that JavaScript, and most bots do not process
>   JavaScript.

Comment: This is not an option. I just want something like stackoverflow has to count pageviews

Comment: In SO, the measurement for counting is IP Address. You can check your question page in two state (after log in and after log out) and see result.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate some kind of CAPTCHA in your application to limit the number of times a user can view the page within a specific amount of time.

Upon a set number of views within a given duration (*say, 20 views in under 3 minutes*) from the same user or IP, make them verify the CAPTCHA each subsequent time they try to view the page.

Answer (score 0):

Issue a `Token` for every page view request. Store the token in the Cookie.

User your already available IP or USER_ID as a filtering mechanism.

After page loaded, User the `token`, `old_token` from the cookie, `Operating System`, `Browser Name` and `IP` / `User_ID` to validate the request.

Give **two different timings**, like 200 second expiration time and 3600 seconds of grace time, if any of the above data matches within the grace time, don't count the page view.

You can also extend this by keeping track of page views within grace time and create some methods to validate pageview request.

Answer (score 0):

I usually register the Request Time together with the Request to measure the Visit Frequency and the Visiter Count per certain Time Span.
When you register all the Request that come in with with the `item_id`, `user_id`, `ip` and `timestamp` you can afterwards process the Registers by grouping them by `user_id`, `ip` and `timestamp`.
That way you can find out the amount of Hits per Second and identify and exclude those who clear surpass the normal Activity Pattern without loosing Data.

Often I use the Web Service Logs to generate Statistics about Visit Frequency to certain URLs on a hourly, daily or even monthly basis.